# CakePHP & MySql search multiple tables with common field 'productname'

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, search, cakephp-1.3

In my database i have got multiple tables with the same field 'productname' and i would like to be able to create a search bar to search all of them.

> SELECT * FROM `mobiles`, 'tablets', 'telephones', 'gopros' WHERE productname LIKE '%app%'

The query is incorrect i know but i'm trying to create something like this in cakephp.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You will need to deliver your table schema, and let us know what you are trying to have returned from the SQL statement. Do you want specific columns of data, everything, ... what?

Comment: how are your models associated so we can come up with what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/union.html) clause,

```
(SELECT * from mobiles WHERE productname LIKE '%app%' )
UNION
(SELECT * from tablets WHERE productname LIKE '%app%' ) ......
```

Comment: Cake does not support UNION through the ORM.

Answer (score 0):

I think this query will provide you the answer

```
SELECT * FROM mobiles AS M, 'tablets' AS T, 'telephones' AS TP, 'gopros' AS G WHERE   M.productname LIKE '%app%' AND T.productname LIKE '%app%' AND TP.productname LIKE '%app%' AND G.productname LIKE '%app%'
```

I hope mobiles tablest etc are tables having productname column